# Adding "Drop shadow" effect for text

Tags: shadows, text-object

I try to find some way of adding "Drop Shadow" effect for text.
Something like on picture which attached.
Something similar to Emission surface but here it need to be some color and I want black color so simple kind of soft shadow.
Maybe some way to add it on post processing?

[image]

---

Maybe I will be more precise cause this is not exactly what I want to achieve. This is exactly kind of effect what I expect:

[image]

So very soft shadow.
In addition, on back of text there is no any layer or other object on which shadow will be drop, so shadow in that case is displayed "in air".
[Marty Fouts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/42221/marty-fouts) i am not sure if with any of your techniques I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

A simple Sun Lamp should suffice.
Use *Sun > Angle* value to control the softness.

[image]

Comment: have problem with that solution. i need backdrop to be invisible. When use shadow catcher, it get scene background looks. It is long animation and it needs background to be not transparent and i need to see object behind text. Event if i make transparent background then cannot see through shadow catcher and cannot see object behind

Comment: Hi :). I'm kinda confused by that description. Perhaps adding the shadow in compositor would be more suitable ;)

Comment: Yes, i also was thinking about compositor. But is is possible to add that kind of effect in compositor?

Comment: ok, got what expected with that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7TjigPt1RA :)

Answer (score 0):

- You could use [this technique](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248177/42221) from [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/78972/jachym-michal) which has much in its favor.
- You could download and use a free [Drop Shadow Font](https://www.1001fonts.com/drop-shadow-fonts.html). That has the advantage that a font designer was all clever and stuff creating the font.
- You could duplicate and offset the text:

  - place the duplicate slightly behind the original
  - Give it a black material with no Specular and a roughness of 1.

  [image: Drop shadow by duplicating the original]

  This has the advantage that you can easily control the "shadow"'s material properties and don't need a specific backdrop.
- According to one professor I had in college, 'things come in threes', so that should be all of the useful techniques; but according to another "if you can think of three, someone else will think of a fourth.  I can think of two more, but I'll leave them as an exercise.